# Hide ROW_NUMBER() in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, row-number

I have a query like

```
Select *
From y
WHERE y.z = (
SELECT a, (adding rownumber here)
FROM b
)
```

I want to add a clause where it only selects every second row. To do this I need to add row_number() to the subquery, and have a clause where rownumber % 2 = 0.

My question is, am I able to add rownumber to the select of the subquery and somehow hide it so it doesn't affect the query

Comment: MySQL lacks an inbuilt `ROWNUM` capability.

Comment: You can nest the subquery in another query that only selects the fields you want; in order to only get "every second row", you may need to anyway (the most common way I've seen of creating "row numbers" in MySQL involves session variables that don't work predictably when used across different clauses in a query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rownumbering in MySQL is a notorious pain in the neck.

You can number your rows in MySQL like this.

```
           SELECT (@rownum := @rownum+1) rownum, b.*
             FROM b
             JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) init
            ORDER BY b.whatever
```

Don't forget the `ORDER BY` clause here. Without explicit ordering the query engine is free to randomize the order of rows it returns.

Then, you can use that mess as a subquery and do things with the `rownum`.

```
 SELECT *
   FROM (
               SELECT (@rownum := @rownum+1) rownum, b.*
                 FROM b
                 JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) init
                ORDER BY b.whatever
         ) table_with_rownum
   WHERE rownum % 2 = 0
```

If you don't want to show the rownumbers, change your `SELECT` from `SELECT *` to `SELECT col, col, col` and leave out `rownum`.